# Package ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a project which is in folder structure -

```
MY_PROJECT
|
|-->Folder_1
|   |-->__init__.py
|   
|   |-->module1.py
|   
|-->run.py
```

`__init__.py` file is empty. When I try to import functions from `module1.py` file from `run.py` by using

```
from Folder_1.module1 import *
```

I run into `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Folder_1.module1'`.

I also tried:

```
from .Database_Scripts.database_utils import *
```

I ran into `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

Additional steps tried -

- I tried putting
  `from module1 import *` into `__init__.py` but I still get the same error.
- using the following code in run.py before importing the module -

  ```
  import sys
  sys.path.insert(1,'path_to_present_directory/Folder_1'
  ```

but to no avail.

Comment: Use `from Folder_1 import module1` as suggested in @hd1's answer.

Comment: They seem to have tried this, and it hasn't worked, I've invited them to screen share with me, where I'll help them further

Answer (score 0):

I duplicated your folder structure, added `from Folder_1 import module1` and had no issues importing it on 3.8. Can you try that and see if it sorts you?

Comment: Unfortunately, the same error. I am using a virtual environment (venv) not sure if that would cause any problems.

Comment: It shouldn't, but I wonder if you could get into a chatroom with me so I could see your screen and help further?

Comment: Sure, not aware of a chatroom, but would be happy to join, if that solves this problem.

Comment: https://zoom.us/wc/3682011339/start will be around for a few hours

Comment: Can we try this after a few hours? Almost about to Sleep, would you be open to chat around 11:00am CST please if you are okay?

Comment: oh ok, I'm on the west coast, so will check in the morning and, if you haven't accepted an answer, I'll leave another comment and we can do a screenshare

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223641/discussion-between-hd1-and-steve-greenwood).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this one time where I had special characters in the folder name. Try to make sure there are no spaces or special characters.